# The usage of "as much as" with "times"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I'm a bit confused on how to use " as much/many as" structure..

here my sentences..I would like you to check them if they are ok please

> 1.The factory A consumes electricity as much as the factory B does.
>
> 2.The factory A consumes  as much electricity as the factory B does.
>
> 3.The factory A consumes as much electricity as 10 times the factory B does. 
>   (For me this sentence mean The factories A and B consumer 10 times
>   more than usual.)
>
> 4.The factory A consumes as much electricity as 10 times than the factory B does.
>
> 5.The factory A consumes as much electricity as 10 times more than the factory B does.
>
> 6.The factory A consumes electricity 10 times more than the factory B does.
>
> 7.The factory A consumes 10 times  as much electricity as the factory B does
>
> 8.Ths table takes up 3 times as much large as the old one.
>
> 9.This table takes up 3 times as much as the old one.
>
> 10.The diameter of the Sun is about 400 times larger than the Moon's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use "the" in front of "factory A" and "factory B". They act as proper nouns here.

When you use "as much as", the second "as" goes before the second noun. The object of the verb goes after "as much". Multiples or additions go before "as much". It works like this:

> (Factory A) (consumes) (electricity)
>
> (subject) (verb) (object)
>
> (Factory A) (consumes) as much (electricity) as (Factory B) (does)
>
> (subject) (verb) as much (object) as (other noun) (optional verb)

The verb at the end is sometimes dropped. Keep it if the tense is different, or if it adds more information. For example, this sentence implies that Factory B shut down, or maybe that Factory A replaced Factory B:

> Factory A consumes as much electricity as Factory B **did**.

This sentence compares Factory A and Factory B at different times:

> Factory A consumes as much electricity during the day as Factory B does at night.

Here are some correct versions of your examples:

> Factory A consumes as much electricity as Factory B does.
>
> Factory A consumes as much electricity as Factory B.
>
> Factory A consumes ten times as much electricity as Factory B does.
>
> Factory A consumes half as much electricity as Factory B.
>
> Factory A consumes 50 kilowatts more than Factory B does.
>
> This table is three times as large as the old one was.
>
> This table takes up three times as much space as the old one did.
>
> This table seats three times as many people as the old one.
>
> Charlotte, North Carolina has as many people as Fort Worth, Texas.
>
> Boston has twice as many people as St. Louis.
>
> Boston has as many people as London did in 1720.
>
> In 1720, London had as many people as Boston does now.

"As many" is used for discrete, countable things like people or hours. "As much" is used for continuous things like water or time. For example:

> as many dollars
>
> as much money

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mind asking on the sentence "This table seats three times as many people as the old one", does it mean "the new one is 3 times bigger than the old one " ?

Comment: Not exactly. Saying that the table is "bigger" is vague. It could mean that the table is longer, or has more surface area, or is taller. Talking about size is okay, but sometimes talking about the number of seats is more helpful. Here are the same examples with context:

This table is three times as large as the old one was. We couldn't fit it through the door!

This table takes up three times as much space as the old one. There's no room left for a sofa!

This table seats three times as many people as the old one. I can invite all of my friends to my dinner party!

Comment: Thank you for your answer again.Actually what I meant is that does the sentence imply the new one and old one is not equal, doesnt it?

Comment: Correct. They're not equal.